# Does Atomicity guarantee every thread sees the same value?

Tags: multithreading, atomic

I know that Atomicity is the guarantee that no other thread sees partial or transient state changes, they only see consistent states. But could it be the old state or always the new state?

Assume we have 3 threads. Thread 1 updates a variable Atomically. Now are the other 2 threads guaranteed to see the new value or it's possible some see the old value?

Comment: this is more about memory barrier than atomicity

Answer (score 0):

Atomicity and visibility are different guarantees. Almost every CPU you are likely to use guarantees that native-sized aligned reads and writes are atomic. But most of them don't guarantee that such reads and writes are visible immediately.

Comment: In terms of "memory models", in a TSO model (like x86) or even stronger one with Sequential Consistency, is visibility still an issue? i.e instructions are executed in order but the output may not be visible to another thread yet?

Comment: @Dan There are two separate issues: 1) Does the formal specification guarantee it will work? 2) In practice, what will happen? But the gist of it is that buffered writes and speculative reads can cause visibility issues as can, if you're not writing raw instructions, compiler optimizations.